# How do I constrain a fitted curve through specific points like the origin in MATLAB, also implementing gradient

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

*I know, I know, that there are several similar Questions already on this and other forums. I read and tried them all...Didn't work for me though.*

I followed [this](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94272-how-do-i-constrain-a-fitted-curve-through-specific-points-like-the-origin-in-matlab) MATLAB post to solve my problems, here the code

```
x0 = Xh(end,1); %end point of previous curve to add on
y0 = fh(end,1); %end point of previous curve to add on

x = A.data(co2:end,1); %a 17280 x 1 double of real data (shaky)
y = A.data(co2:end,31); %a 17280 x 1 double of real data (shaky)
% 'C' is the Vandermonde matrix for 'x'
n = 25; % Degree of polynomial to fit
V(:,n+1) = ones(length(x),1,class(x));
for j = n:-1:1
     V(:,j) = x.*V(:,j+1);
end
C = V;
% 'd' is the vector of target values, 'y'.
d = y;
%%
% There are no inequality constraints in this case, i.e., 
A = [];
b = [];
%%
% We use linear equality constraints to force the curve to hit the required point. In
% this case, 'Aeq' is the Vandermoonde matrix for 'x0'
Aeq = x0.^(n:-1:0);
% and 'beq' is the value the curve should take at that point
beq = y0;
%% 
p = lsqlin( C, d, A, b, Aeq, beq )
%%
% We can then use POLYVAL to evaluate the fitted curve
yhat = polyval( p, x );
%%
% Plot original data
plot(x,y,'.b-') 
hold on
% Plot point to go through
plot(x0,y0,'gx','linewidth',4) 
% Plot fitted data
plot(x,yhat,'g','linewidth',2) 
hold off
```

This code works perfect for me in terms of fitting the curve and forcing it to go through my starting point. But in terms of adding the curve to a previous smoothly, the starting point should have the same gradient than the previous curve ended on. Also it should end on a fixed point wiht fixed gradient.

**So the implementations I need are:**

---

> add more then one fixed point ([x0,y0],[x1,y1],...)
>
> set the gradient at the fixed x0,x1,...

*I know [polyfix](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54207-polyfix-x-y-n-xfix-yfix-xder-dydx-) did this before, but the fitting process in this code doesn't work in my case. the results of `lsqlin` are much better. Still this is kind of what I'm looking for.*

**Can you help me to edit the code above to add those features?**

Comment: No. "gimme teh codez" questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Add the features yourself and come back when you have a _specific question or error_.

Answer (score 1):

You should add more constraint equation to your optimisation problem, f.e.:

```
Aeq(1, :) = x0.^(n:-1:0);
beq(1, :) = x0;
Aeq(2, :) = x1.^(n:-1:0);
beq(2, :) = y1;
Aeq(3, 1:end-1) = x0.^(n-1:-1:0) .* (n:-1:1);
beq(3, :) = dy0;
Aeq(4, 1:end-1) = x1.^(n-1:-1:0) .* (n:-1:1);
beq(4, :) = dy1;
```

To derive the equation of the first derivative constraint, it is a good idea to try it first by hand for a small polynomial order.

**Example**

The following input:

```
p_exact = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;
dy0 = 0;
x1 = 1;
y1 = 10;
dy1 = 100;

x = (0:0.001:1)';
y = polyval( p_exact, x )+randn(size(x));
n = 7; % Degree of polynomial to fit
```

generates this output:

[image]

You clearly see the effect of the constraints on your fitted curve, i.e. compare the red and green curve.