# Matlab - Fit a Curve with Constrained Parameters

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

For a (`x`,`y`) dataset, let have a curve given by an expression in `a`, `b`,`c`... etc, such as `f='a*exp(b*x)+c'`, to be fitted as `cfit=fit(x,y,f)`.

Suppose we have a set of constraint such as `b>0`, `c+b>a/2`. How should i use the `fit` command in this case?.

Comment: While this sounds similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45095979/52738), I'm not convinced it's a duplicate. That question deals with constraining points of the fitted line, whereas this question just wants to constrain parameters to a range.

Comment: Yes, the toolbox allows to deal with outliers, which is in the xy space, but i am asking about the parameter space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For constraints that are just numeric values, such as `b > 0`, you can use the [`'Lower'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html#input_argument_d0e31960) and [`'Upper'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html#input_argument_d0e32011) bounds arguments to specify those. For more complex relationships, like `c+b>a/2`, you'll have to take an approach like [James suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46180711/52738), setting the function output to a high value like [`flintmax`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flintmax.html) to generate a large error. For example, let's say I define my function like this:

```
function y = my_fcn(a, b, c, x)
  if (c+b > a/2)
    y = a.*exp(b.*x)+c;
  else
    y = flintmax().*ones(size(x));
  end
end
```

I can create a set of noisy test data as follows:

```
a = 4;
b = 2;
c = 1;
x = (0:0.01:2).';
y = my_fcn(a, b, c, x) + 40.*(rand(size(x))-0.5);
```

And then fit a curve (note you have to use an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), since a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) won't work for some reason):

```
params = fit(x, y, @(a, b, c, x) my_fcn(a, b, c, x), ...
             'StartPoint', [1 1 1], ...  % Starting guesses for [a b c]
             'Lower', [-Inf 0 -Inf]);    % Set bound for 'b'

params = 

     General model:
     params(x) = my_fcn(a,b,c,x)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a =       4.297  (2.985, 5.609)
       b =       1.958  (1.802, 2.113)
       c =      0.1908  (-4.061, 4.442)
```

Note that the fitted values are close to the original values, but don't match exactly due to the noise. We can visualize the fit like so:

```
plot(x, y);
hold on;
plot(x, my_fcn(params.a, params.b, params.c, x), 'r');
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

While you could set a lower boundary to enforce `b>0`, I don't think it is somehow possible to properly enforce `c+b>a/2` with `fit()`. But ultimately every fitting problem can also be regarded as a "minimize the distance from the curve to the data" problem, so `fmincon()` can be used to achieve your goal:

```
%some sample x values
xdata = rand(1000,1);
%some parameters a,b,c
a = 2;
b = 3;
c = 4;
%resulting y values + some noise
ydata=a*exp(b*xdata)+c+rand(1000,1)*10-5;
plot(xdata,ydata,'o')

%function to minimize. It returns the sum of squared distances between the polynom and the data.
fun = @(coefs) sum((coefs(1)*exp(coefs(2).*xdata)+coefs(3)-ydata).^2);
%nonlinear constaint to enforce c+b>a/2, which is the same as -(c+b-a/2)<0
nonlcon = @(coefs)deal(-(coefs(3)+coefs(2)-coefs(1)/2), 0);
% lower bounds to enforce b>0
lb = [-inf 0 -inf];
%starting values
x0 = [1 1 1];
%finally find the coefficients (which should approximately be the values of a, b and c)
coefs = fmincon(fun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,[],nonlcon)
```

Answer (score 2):

One simplistic method is to have the fitted function return a very large value, with resulting very large error, if the parameter values are outside of the constraints. This "brick wall" method is not optimal and will cause problems when the fitted parameter values are close to the boundary conditions. It is worth a try because it is quick to implement and can work in simple cases. Take care to start with initial parameter values within the boundary limits.

Comment: Yes i am using that, for example, replacing `0<b<1` by `atan(abs(b))/pi*2`. But i am sure there should be a better choice. Matlab has a very whole Curve Fitting toolbox without being able to contraint those fitting? I am surprised.

Comment: Though, i am not sure how one could introduce, in the given case, a large error when `b`~1.